# What purpose do kolelim serve post yeshiva education

Tags: adult-learning

It seems there are kolelim everywhere.
Are they to become educators, dayanim, or are they for learning torah for its own sake.

Comment: All of the above

Comment: Their purpose is to ensure the continuity of knowledge of the Torah in *klal yisrael* in any / all forms.

Comment: I would imagine this varies from kollel to kollel.

Answer (score 2):

The foundation of learning in Kollel is because of the Chyiuv (obligation) of Talmud Torah. See [Hilchos Talmud Torah](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15605&st=&pgnum=217), Shulchan Aruch HaRav where he [writes](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15605&st=&pgnum=237) that after marriage a person can easily learn for around 2-3 years full-time before he has many children and the burden of supporting his family might be too much.

A person is only exempt from the mitzvah of Talmud Torah in order to make a parnasah (livelihood). Even when it comes to Yeshivos, their foundation is not only in order to receive a Jewish “education”, it’s because of the mitzvah of Talmud Torah. Notice the schedule of Yeshiva isn’t from 8:00am-3:00pm like secular schools which would be enough to have more than just a general Jewish knowledge. For this same reason the focus in Yeshivos is not the learning of Halacha, which is more relevant. Instead, the focus is the study of Talmud which is the main body of the [Mitzvah of Yedias Hatorah](https://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/sh/sh5/6/2/index.htm) (the obligation for every Jew to *engage* in the Mitzvah to know the whole Torah [in Pardes](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15605&st=&pgnum=209&hilite=): Remez, Pshat, and Sod).